# What is the best way to concurrently decrease a column value with Entity Framework and .NET?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, concurrency, transactions

Let's say I have a table `Employees` with a column `Counter` with an initial value of 100. From an ASP.NET MVC application with Entity Framework 6, I want to decrease this counter by *1* when a button is clicked by any user.

I would like to perform something like this:

```
// find employee with id 1001
var employee = context.Employees.Find(1001);

// decrease by 1 the Counter column of employee with id 1001
employee.Counter -= 1;
db.SaveChanges();
```

If userA clicks the button for the first time the code will read value 100 and will update to 99.

If userB simultaneously clicks the button and the previous update is not finished yet, will read again value 100 and update to 99. The expected behaviour would be the value to be updated to 98 when both of those transactions have finished.

How can I decrease the value in an isolated way?

Is one of the below ways preferable? Can you give me example code?

1. Lock object
2. TransactionScope
3. Calling stored procedure
4. Entity Framework transaction

Comment: A trigger in the DB?

Comment: Your EF context has a BeginTransaction method to handle this

Comment: EF or EF Core? Which version?

Comment: Version is EF 6

Answer (score 1):

In EF Core v7+, [you can use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/execute-insert-update-delete) `ExecuteUpdate` or `ExecuteUpdateAsync`

```cs
await context.Employees
    .Where(e => e.Id == 1001)
    .ExecuteUpdateAsync(setter => setter
        .SetProperty(e => e.Counter, e => e.Counter - 1)
        , someCancellationToken);
```

This generates a single `UPDATE` statement, which executes atomically as usual.

You can also do multiple columns together, and use constant values, and do it synchronously if you want.

```cs
context.Employees
    .Where(e => e.Id == 1001)
    .ExecuteUpdate(setter => setter
        .SetProperty(e => e.Counter, e => e.Counter - 1)
        .SetProperty(e => e.UpdateTime, DateTime.UtcNow)
    );
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the version is EF 6, it is not core.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best practice for this is to create stored procedure.